# JBoss AS7: ServletContextListener#contextInitialized called after Servlet instantiation

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy my webservice (originally running on JBoss AS5) on the new JBoss AS7 (Everything) Final.
The problem is that i used a ServletContextListener to initialize my environment (f.e. to initialize the resource management).
But when I try to deploy the war file on JBoss AS 7 the configured Servlets are instantiated before the #contextInitialized-method of the listener is called (wich cases an Exception because a mandatory resource can not be found).

My listener:

```
@WebListener
public class StandardStartup implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        //destroy environment
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        //initialize environment
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>any.displayname</display-name>
 <listener>
  <display-name>Startup</display-name>
  <listener-class>any.StandardStartup</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AnyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>any.AnyServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AnyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AnyServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can someone explain me why the listener is not called before the instantiation of the servlets (maybe with a possible workaround) or knows what I am doing wrong?
PS.: I tried to implement the listener as a Servlet and set the load-on-startup to 0, but JBoss AS7 says I have declare a servlet-mapping which I do not want in that case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a very similar issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately I had to change my design not to use the resources, which would have been accessed in the constructor.